# Android Fragment (with Compatibility Package on 2.3.3) creates "Specified child already has a parent error"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using fragments in my Android application using the compatibility package. I have tested the application on a Nexus One running 2.3.3 and an Google API 2.2 emulator.

When adding the fragment via the layout XML it works great (using a fragment tag).

When adding the fragment dynamically into a FrameLayout it does not successfully add the fragment to the container and it throws the following error.

```
alStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

Full stacktrace for this is below.

```
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:743)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1219)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:380)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-17 19:44:03.518: DEBUG/UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION(7735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:743)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1219)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:380)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-17 19:44:03.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the layout I'm using - the FrameLayout is the container I'm inserting into.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/activity_phone_tabbedview_scroll">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <Button android:text="Something" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tabs"
                android:textColor="@color/White" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:textSize="19sp"
                android:onClick="Something" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" android:text="Something"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="19sp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="Something"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" android:text="Something"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="19sp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="Something"></Button>

            <Button android:text="Something" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/tabs"
                android:textColor="@color/White" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:textSize="19sp" 
                android:onClick="Something"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/activity_phone_tabbedviewer_fragment_container" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_phone_tabbedview_scroll">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code I'm using to actually insert the fragment is below.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
NewsList newsList = new NewsList();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_phone_tabbedviewer_fragment_container, newsList);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Can you post the content of your `onCreateView(...)` method in the `NewsList` `Fragment`?

I'm guessing that you are calling `LayoutInflater.inflate(...)` at some point.  If so you need to use the [overloaded version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29) and pass `attachToRoot` as `false` as the `View` will be added to the hierachy in the `Fragment.replace(...)` call, so should not be attached during inflation.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that suggestion worked perfectly. Adding false so it uses the overloaded version worked.

Comment: Hot damn. I wasted so many hours to fix this and it was a matter of one 'false'. Thanks!

Comment: WOW. Same here. 40 minutes wasted. If my class EXTENDS Fragment, does it follow then that I must ALWAYS override onCreateView, just so I can set that 'false' parameter? If so...plghghgh!

Answer (score 11):

Thanks a lot! To make it more trivial, here is how this worked for me:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Call the specific overload of inflate
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, null, false);
}
```

Comment: even i am using like this also getting error View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, null, false);