# Select photo from Android Gallery then display it in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an Android app using fragments and would like the user to be able to pick an image for scanning purposes. I have a fragment that allows the user to select their desired source (camera, hand-drawn, or gallery). When the user selects Gallery, then another fragment should display the image. I already know how I am supposed to get the image into an `ImageView` but keep getting this error with the Fragments:

```
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nathanmoos.artificialIntelligence.clockreader/org.nathanmoos.artificialIntelligence.clockreader.ChooseSourceActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1371)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:499)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:3821)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3826)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
12-10 17:30:26.405: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     ... 10 more
```

Basically it looks like there's an issue with my `FragmentTransaction` usage. Here's my code:

```
frag = new GalleryFragment();
frag.setImagePath(imagePath);

FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.fragment_space, frag);
tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
```

and my layout file:

```
   <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/fragment_space"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="65"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured this one out. It's the same solution as:

[Android Fragment (with Compatibility Package on 2.3.3) creates "Specified child already has a parent error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035711/android-fragment-with-compatibility-package-on-2-3-3-creates-specified-child)
and
[Error swapping / adding an XML Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042859/error-swapping-adding-an-xml-fragment)
.