# What does the LayoutInflater attachToRoot parameter mean?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater

The [`LayoutInflater.inflate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29) documentation isn't exactly clear to me about the purpose of the `attachToRoot` parameter.

> *attachToRoot*: whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct
>   subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

Could someone please explain in more detail, specifically what the root view is, and maybe show an example of a change in behavior between `true` and `false` values?

Comment: Related: [Making sense of LayoutInflater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326314/what-is-the-use-of-attach-to-root-in-layout-inflater

Answer (score 286):

## NOW OR NOT NOW

The main difference between the "third" parameter attachToRoot being true or false is this.

> When you put attachToRoot

**true :** add the child view to parent **RIGHT NOW**
**false:** add the child view to parent **NOT NOW**.
Add it later. `

> When is that **later**?

That later is when you use eg `parent.addView(childView)`

**A common misconception** is, if attachToRoot parameter is false then the child view will not be added to parent. **WRONG**
In both cases, child view will be added to parentView. It is just a matter of **time**.

```
inflater.inflate(child,parent,false);
parent.addView(child);
```

**is equivalent to**

```
inflater.inflate(child,parent,true);
```

**A BIG NO-NO**
You should never pass attachToRoot as true when you are not responsible for adding the child view to the parent.
Eg When adding Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle bundle)
  {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,parent,bundle);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,parent,false);
        .....
        return view;
  }
```

if you pass third parameter as true you will get IllegalStateException because of this guy.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(parent, childFragment)
      .commit();
```

Since you have already added the child fragment in onCreateView() by mistake, calling add will tell you that child view is already added to the parent Hence **IllegalStateException**.
Here you are not responsible for adding childView, FragmentManager is responsible. So always pass false in this case.

**NOTE:** I have also read that parentView will not get childView touchEvents if attachToRoot is false. But I have not tested it though.

Comment: Very helpful, especially the part regarding the `FragmentManager`, thank you!

Comment: very well explained. this should be part of Android docs. it wasn't clear for me when I read android docs

Answer (score 102):

If set to true then when your layout is inflated it will be automatically added to the view hierarchy of the ViewGroup specified in the 2nd parameter as a child. For example if the root parameter was a `LinearLayout` then your inflated view will be automatically added as a child of that view.

If it is set to false then your layout will be inflated but won't be attached to any other layout (so it won't be drawn, receive touch events etc).

Comment: I'm confused.  I was getting a "Specified child already has a parent error” until I read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036484/403455), which directed my to use `false` for `attachToRoot` during my Fragment's `onCreateView`.  This solved the problem and yet the fragment's layout is visible and active, despite your answer.  What's going on here?

Comment: Because a Fragment automatically attaches the layout returned from onCreateView. So if you attach it manually in onCreateView then your view gets attached to 2 parents (which produces the error you mention).

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, @JosephEarl you said if set to `true`, the view is attached to 2nd parameter which is the `container`, but then you say fragment is automatically attached from `onCreateView()`, so to my understanding, third parameter is useless and should be set `false` always?

Comment: You return the view in oncreateview, this is then automatically attached. If you set attach to true, an error is thrown. However, when you inflate the view in a standalone situation, you can choose to attach the view to its container automatically by setting to true. I hardly ever set to true though as I always add the view myself.

Comment: @unmultimedio it is only useless for the root view returned by `onCreateView`. If you inflate further layouts into that root view, or you are inflating in a different context (e.g. in an Activity) then it is useful.

Comment: What are the other ways of having the third parameter set to true?

Comment: Not drawn ? I think passing null parent will still draw the view though it's not gonna set the attachToRoot parameter since there will be no parent to attach. I can also say that it's gonna receive touch events either but they don't propagated to the parent ( since they don't  have ). Missing something ?

Answer (score 43):

Seems like a lot of text in the responses but no code, that's why I decided to revive this old question with a code example, in several responses people mentioned:

> If set to true then when your layout is inflated it will be automatically added to the view hierarchy of the ViewGroup specified in the 2nd parameter as a child.

What that actually means in code(what most programmers understand) is:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyCustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Inflate the view from the layout resource and pass it as child of mine (Notice I'm a LinearLayout class).

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.child_view, this, true);
    }
}
```

Notice that previous code is adding the layout `R.layout.child_view` as child of `MyCustomLayout` because of `attachToRoot` param is `true` and assigns the layout params of the parent exactly in the same way as if I would be using `addView` programmatically, or as if I did this in xml:

> ```
> <LinearLayout>
>    <View.../>
>    ...
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

The following code explains the scenario when passing `attachRoot` as `false`:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Create a stand-alone view
View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.ownRootView, null, false);
linearLayout.addView(myView);
```

In the previous code you specify that you wanted `myView` to be it's own root object and do not attach it to any parent, later on we added it as part of the `LinearLayout` but for a moment it was a stand-alone (no parent) view.

Same thing happens with Fragments, you could add them to an already existing group and be part of it, or just pass the parameters:

> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null, false);

To specify that it will be it's own root.

Comment: Out of all, this was the most helpful.

Answer (score 28):

The documentation and the two previous answers should be enough, just some thoughts from me.

The `inflate` method is used to inflate layout files. With those inflated layouts you have to possibility to attach them directly to a parent `ViewGroup` or just inflate the view hierarchy from that layout file and work with it outside of the normal view hierarchy.

In the first case the `attachToRoot` parameter will have to be set to `true`(or much simple use the `inflate` method that takes a layout file and a parent root `ViewGroup`(non `null`)). In this case the `View` returned is simply the `ViewGroup` that was passed in the method, the `ViewGroup` to which  the inflated view hierarchy will be added.

For the second option the returned `View` is the root `ViewGroup` from the layout file. If you remember our last discussion from the [`include-merge` pair question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12518446/403455) this is one of the reasons for the `merge`'s limitation(when a layout file with `merge` as root is inflated, you must supply a parent and `attachedToRoot` must be set to `true`). If you had a layout file with the root a `merge` tag and `attachedToRoot` was set to `false` then the `inflate` method will have nothing to return as `merge` doesn't have an equivalent.
Also, as the documentation says, the `inflate` version with `attachToRoot` set to `false` is important because you can create the view hierarchy with the correct `LayoutParams` from the parent. This is important in some cases, most notable with the children of `AdapterView`, a subclass of `ViewGroup`, for which the `addView()` methods set is not supported. I'm sure you recall using this line in the `getView()` method:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
```

This line ensures that the inflated `R.layout.row_layout` file has the correct `LayoutParams` from the `AdapterView` subclass set on its root `ViewGroup`. If you wouldn't be doing this you could have some problems with the layout file if the root was a `RelativeLayout`. The `TableLayout/TableRow` also have some special and important `LayoutParams` and you should make sure the views in them have the correct `LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 28):

I wrote this answer because even after going through several StackOverflow pages I wasn't able to clearly grasp what attachToRoot meant. Below is inflate() method in the LayoutInflater class.

```
View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

Take a look at *activity_main.xml* file, *button.xml* layout and the *MainActivity.java* file I created.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

button.xml

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, root, false);
}
```

When we run the code, we won't see the button in the layout. This is because our button layout is not added into the main activity layout since attachToRoot is set to false.

LinearLayout has an *addView(View view)* method which can be used to add Views to LinearLayout. This will add the button layout into the main activity layout, and make the button visible when you run the code.

```
root.addView(view);
```

Let's remove the previous line, and see what happens when we set attachToRoot as true.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, root, true);
```

Again we see that the button layout is visible. This is because attachToRoot directly attaches the inflated layout to the parent specified. Which in this case is root LinearLayout. Here we don't have to add the views manually like we did in the previous case with addView(View view) method.

**Why are people getting IllegalStateException when setting attachToRoot as true for a Fragment.**

This is because for a fragment you have already specified where to place your fragment layout in your activity file.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.root, fragment)
    .commit();
```

The *add(int parent, Fragment fragment)* adds the fragment which has it's layout to the parent layout. If we set attachToRoot as true, you will get IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. Since fragment layout is already added to the parent layout in the add() method.

**You should always pass false for attachToRoot when you're inflating Fragments. It is the FragmentManager’s job to add, remove and replace Fragments.**

Back to my example. What if we do both.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, root, true);
root.addView(view);
```

In the first line, LayoutInflater attaches the button layout to the root layout and returns a View object which holds the same button layout. In the second line, we add the same View object to the parent root layout. This results in the same IllegalStateException we saw with Fragments (The specified child already has a parent).

Keep in mind that there is another overloaded inflate() method, which sets attachToRoot as true by default.

```
View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)
```

Comment: Simple and clear explanation, just what I was looking for!

Comment: This is the ONLY answer on here that explains that `attachToRoot` is set to `true` by default when omitted (which is counter intuitive)

Comment: clear explanation !! clears the confusion regarding this

Answer (score 21):

I myself was also confused about what was the real purpose of `attachToRoot` in `inflate` method. After a bit of UI study, I finally got the answer:

**parent:**

in this case is the widget/layout that is surrounding the view objects that you want to inflate using findViewById().

**attachToRoot:**

attaches the views to their parent (includes them in the parent hierarchy), so **any touch event that the views recieve will also be transfered to parent view. Now it's upto the parent whether it wants to entertain those events or ignore them.** if set to false, they are not added as direct children of the parent and the parent doesn't recieve any touch events from the views.

Hope this clears the confusion

Comment: You're answer is already provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326314/what-is-the-use-of-attach-to-root-in-layout-inflater

Answer (score 11):

There is a lot of confusion on this topic due to the documentation for the inflate() method.

In general, if attachToRoot is set to true, then the layout file specified in the first parameter is inflated and attached to the ViewGroup specified in the second parameter at that moment in time. When attachToRoot is false, the layout file from the first parameter is inflated and returned as a View and any View attachment happens at some other time.

This probably doesn't mean much unless you see a lot of examples. When calling LayoutInflater.inflate() inside of the onCreateView method of a Fragment, you will want to pass in false for attachToRoot because the Activity associated with that Fragment is actually responsible for adding that Fragment's view. If you are manually inflating and adding a View to another View at some later point in time, such as with the addView() method, you will want to pass in false for attachToRoot because the attachment comes at a later point in time.

You can read about several other unique examples concerning Dialogs and custom Views on a blog post I wrote about this very topic.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 5):

`attachToRoot` set to true means the `inflatedView` will be added to the parent view's hierarchy. Thus can possibly be "seen" and sense touch events (or any other UI operations) by users. Otherwise, it is just been created, not been added to any view hierarchy and thus cannot be seen or handle touch events.

For iOS developers new to Android, `attachToRoot` set to true means you call this method:

```
[parent addSubview:inflatedView];
```

If going further you might ask: Why should I pass parent view if I set `attachToRoot` to `false`? It is because the root element in your XML tree needs the parent view to calculate some LayoutParams (like match parent).

Answer (score 1):

**attachToRoot Set to true:**

> If attachToRoot is set to true, then the layout file specified in the first parameter is inflated and attached to the ViewGroup specified in the second parameter.

Imagine we specified a button in an XML layout file with its layout width and layout height set to match_parent.

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/custom_button">
</Button>
```

We now want to programmatically add this Button to a LinearLayout inside of a Fragment or Activity. If our LinearLayout is already a member variable, mLinearLayout, we can simply add the button with the following:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button, mLinearLayout, true);
```

We specified that we want to inflate the Button from its layout resource file; we then tell the LayoutInflater that we want to attach it to mLinearLayout. Our layout parameters are honored because we know the Button gets added to a LinearLayout. The Button’s layout params type should be LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

**attachToRoot Set to false (not required to use false)**

> If attachToRoot is set to false, then the layout file specified in the first parameter is inflated and **not** attached to the ViewGroup specified in the second parameter but that inflated **view acquires parent's LayoutParams** which enables that view to fit correctly in the parent.

Let’s take a look at when you would want to set attachToRoot to false. In this scenario, the View specified in the first parameter of inflate() is not attached to the ViewGroup in the second parameter at this point in time.

Recall our Button example from earlier, where we want to attach a custom Button from a layout file to mLinearLayout. We can still attach our Button to mLinearLayout by passing in false for attachToRoot—we just manually add it ourselves afterward.

```
Button button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button,    mLinearLayout, false);
mLinearLayout.addView(button);
```

These two lines of code are equivalent to what we wrote earlier in one line of code when we passed in true for attachToRoot. By passing in false, we say that we do not want to attach our View to the root ViewGroup just yet. We are saying that it will happen at some other point in time. In this example, the other point in time is simply the addView() method used immediately below inflation.

The false attachToRoot example requires a bit more work when we manually add the View to a ViewGroup.

**attachToRoot Set to false(false is Required)**
When inflating and returning a Fragment’s View in onCreateView(), be sure to pass in false for attachToRoot. If you pass in true, you will get an IllegalStateException because the specified child already has a parent. You should have specified where your Fragment’s view will be placed back in your Activity. It is the FragmentManager’s job to add, remove and replace Fragments.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment =  fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.root_viewGroup);

if (fragment == null) {
fragment = new MainFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.root_viewGroup, fragment)
    .commit();
}
```

The root_viewGroup container that will hold your Fragment in your Activity is the ViewGroup parameter given to you in onCreateView() in your Fragment. It’s also the ViewGroup you pass into LayoutInflater.inflate(). The FragmentManager will handle attaching your Fragment’s View to this ViewGroup, however. You do not want to attach it twice. Set attachToRoot to false.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  parentViewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,     parentViewGroup, false);
…
return view;
}
```

Why are we given our Fragment’s parent ViewGroup in the first place if we don’t want to attach it in onCreateView()? Why does the inflate() method request a root ViewGroup?
It turns out that even when we are not immediately adding our newly inflated View to its parent ViewGroup, we should still use the parent’s LayoutParams in order for the new View to determine its size and position whenever it is eventually attached.

Link: https://youtu.be/1Y0LlmTCOkM?t=409

Answer (score 0):

When you define the parent the attachToRoot determines whether you want the inflater to actually attach it to the parent or not.  In some cases this causes problems, like in a ListAdapter it will cause an exception because the list tries to add the view to the list but it says it's already attached.  In other cased where you're just inflating the view yourself to add to an Activity it could be handy and save you a line of code.

Comment: does not give a clear picture which a good answer should provide.

Answer (score 0):

For example we have an `ImageView` , a `LinearLayout` and a `RelativeLayout`. LinearLayout is the child of RelativeLayout.
the View Hierarchy will be.

```
RelativeLayout
           ------->LinearLayout
```

and we have a separate layout file for ImageView

**image_view_layout.xml**

**Attach to root:**

```
//here container is the LinearLayout

    View v = Inflater.Inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout,container,true);
```

1. Here v contains the reference of the container layout i.e the
   LinearLayout.and if you want to set the parameters like `setImageResource(R.drawable.np);` of ImageView you will have to find it by the reference of parent i.e `view.findById()`
2. Parent of v will be the FrameLayout.
3. LayoutParams will be of FrameLayout.

**Not attach to root:**

```
//here container is the LinearLayout
    View v = Inflater.Inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout,container,false);
```

1. Here v contains the no reference container layout but direct
   reference to the ImageView that is inflated so you can set its
   parameters like `view.setImageResource(R.drawable.np);` without
   refereing like `findViewById`. But container is specified so that
   ImageView gets the LayoutParams of the container so you can say
   that the reference of container is just for LayoutParams nothing
   else.
2. so in particular case  Parent will be null.
3. LayoutParams will be of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing some points that i encountered while working on this topic,

In addition to the accepted answer i want to some points which could be of some help.

So, when i used ***attachToRoot*** as true, the view which was returned was of type ***ViewGroup*** i.e. parent's root ViewGroup which was passed as parameter for the ***inflate(layoutResource,ViewGroup,attachToRoot)*** method, not of type the layout which was passed but on ***attachToRoot*** as false we get the function return type of that layoutResource's root ***ViewGroup***.

Let me explain with an example:

If we have a ***LinearLayout*** as the ***root*** layout and then we want to add ***TextView*** in it through ***inflate*** function.

then on using ***attachToRoot*** as ***true*** inflate function returns a ***View*** of type ***LinearLayout***

while on using ***attachToRoot*** as ***false*** inflate function returns a ***View*** of type ***TextView***

Hope this finding would be of some help...