# What is the use of "attach to root" in layout inflater?

Tags: android, android-view

I am a newbie to android, I know this question has already been asked but i couldn't get a satisfactory explanation.
My doubts are:

1. What is "attach to root" used for, if possible with a small
   and clear example.
2. When I searched for the answer people said its optional used to
   attach to parent view group, What is the view group hierarchy?(Is
   that considering views that we created programatically or is that
   also considering the views that are already declared in an xml file)

I hope the questions is clear, if not please say so in the comments.

Comment: Check here for a good explanation: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the LayoutInflater attachToRoot parameter mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I myself was also confused about what was the real purpose of `attachToRoot` in `inflate` method. After a bit of UI study, I finally got the answer:

**parent:**

in this case is the widget/layout that is surrounding the view objects that you want to inflate using findViewById().

**attachToRoot:**

attaches the views to their parent (includes them in the parent hierarchy), so **any touch event that the views recieve will also be transfered to parent view. Now it's upto the parent whether it wants to entertain those events or ignore them.** if set to false, they are not added as direct children of the parent and the parent doesn't recieve any touch events from the views.

Hope this clears the confusion

Comment: Thank you for this short and precise explanation!

Comment: This is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809756/7436566

Comment: Is this `attachToRoot` sort of the equivalent of addView? Like it just get's added to the view hierarchy of the parent which is like a container view or view group?

Answer (score 6):

The third parameter in the inflate method has a boolean return type.
There is a lot of **confusion**(Will get to this part soon) when it comes to choosing the value of the parameter.

** It's Simple**

1. When **attachToRoot = false** it means

> Don't attach the child view to parent **"Right Now"**, Add it later.

2. When **attachToRoot = true** it means

> Attach the childView to parent "Right Now".

In both cases, the child view will be added to parentView eventually.
** It's just a matter of time.**
If you want to read in more details you can **refer --->** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean/45809756#45809756) answer
(Because I can not post the duplicate answer here, Happy to help).

Answer (score 3):

**For example :**

> ChildView : TextView
>
> Parent(Container)View : LinearLayout

**if attach to root = true**

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, containerView, true)
// Not need  -> containerView.addView(view) 
// This view will be LinearLayout. Not Textview.
```

**if attach to root = false**

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, containerView, false)
containerView.addView(view) // we should add
// This view will be TextView.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a `ViewGroup` to it, it will add the inflated `View` to that `ViewGroup`. That means, the inflated `View` will be a child of the passed `ViewGroup`.

It is irrelevant whether the ViewGroup is made programatically or by an xml file.

Comment: Consider a scenario where I have declared layouts in the xml and i am dynamically(progrmatically) genreating the textviews then what are all in my viewgroup and what is the parent in that(1st textview or the layout in the xml file)?

Comment: The `ViewGroup` that you want to contain the `TextView`s. If you have a `LinearLayout` in your xml, and you want the dynamically generated `TextView`s to be in that `LinearLayout`, pass that `LinearLayout` as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think :
Attach to root = true means give the parent view the accessibility wither to make another events when the view is clickable or not.

False: means Not to give the parent any accessibility.

group Hierarchy : it means to be added like a child to the parent "View Group"