# Clarification about layout inflater -attach to root?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I read the answer on [Why does LayoutInflater ignore the layout_width and layout_height layout parameters I've specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater) and wanted to make sure i understood what attach to root does.
Basically if you do

```
inflater.inflate(int idOfLayoutFile, ViewGroup parent, boolean AttachToRoot)
```

and lets say parent is not null

From what I got out of that answer was that attach to root just affects what the return type is of the inflate method. That is if `attachToRoot` is `true`, method will return parent, and if it is `false`, the method will return the root view of the XML file as specified by the resource id. Do I have the right idea here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, something is missed!

When you pass `true` as 'attach to root', inflater will inflate specified layout (represented by its ID) **and then attach it to root of parent** and finally return the parent

But when you left 'attach to root' to `false`. the parent hierarchy won't changed and only inflated layout will be returned.

Comment: @committedandroider result of `null` as parent would be `inflate(id, null, false)`

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you are correct** :: *In short terms*

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.your_layout, null);
        return view;
    }
```

- Now as per above code `view` reference will hold the root element for
  the layout `your_layout`
- You can use this `view` reference to find all the child views of this
  parent layout
- You can refer the child `views` here even though the `activity` is not
  created yet

Answer (score 1):

If you read [this](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/) you'll find that you should NOT pass `null` as value of root `ViewGroup` if you do not want to attach it but rather should use the 3-parameter version of `inflater.inflate` with 3rd parameter (attach to root) set to `false`. I.e., do this:

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                 ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate
                               (
                                 R.layout.your_layout, 
                                 container, 
                                 false
                                );
            return view;
        }
```

And from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html):

`root`  Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that **provides a set of `LayoutParams` values for root of the returned hierarchy** (if attachToRoot is false.)

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846146/what-should-i-pass-for-root-when-inflating-a-layout-to-use-for-a-menuitems-acti) is really good.