# How to set listview to its original position?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, programmatically-created

I have spent enough time to make it work for my listview to setProperty "`above`" of layout which `align_parentBottom=true.`

Seems like very easy right? No its not.

Please see this image so you can visualize the problem and have some idea about it.

[image]

When User `scrolls listview`, home button @bottom hides.

And by default, home button stays as it is if list scrolling is in idle state. This needs to be done.

So my problem is that After home button `Visibility` goes `GONE` then `listview` fills whole space towards bottom means `MATCH_PARENT`, thats fine.

But when scroll reaches to idle state & `Visibility` set to `Visible` then last Item of listview goes/hides behind home button.

It means `listview` is not getting to its original place as Image shows.

Tried By making it programmatically to set "above" property of list as Home Button is `align_parentBottom=true`.

also tried by changing whole layout to Linear layout and giving `weight=1`.

But didn't succeed. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Layout File Fragement:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llmain"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d_5"
        style="@style/text_size_title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d_5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDateTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/comment_n_time_color_text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d_1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_3"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_3"
            android:background="@color/comment_n_time_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_3"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_3"
            android:textColor="@color/comment_n_time_color_text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d_1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_3"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_3"
            android:background="@color/comment_n_time_color" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/comment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_3"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_3"
            android:textColor="@color/comment_n_time_color_text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/article_detail_separator"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d_5"
        android:background="@color/comment_n_time_color"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d_5"
        android:text="@string/article_comment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d_5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/article_comment_hint"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_send"
            android:padding="@dimen/d_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/send_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:listSelector="@null">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And My Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbaar"
        layout="@layout/partial_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbaar"
        android:id="@+id/viewline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/separator_color" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_above="@+id/llbottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewline"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/img_home_"
            layout="@layout/home_icon_footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your layout file plz

Comment: post your layout please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this issue by

> listview.scrollTo(0 , homeBtn.getHeight());

Which actually moves my list items to scroll on up Y direction when I get last item or say When there is not the first item of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to solve your problem by having one parent view, lets just say a relative view, and then have **three different views inside that relative view**. So it would look like relative view then inside that you can have a view for your elements above the list View, then a ScrollView with your listview inside that and finally another view, probably a relative view, after that for the home button and make sure to **align_parentBottom=true**.

Comment: And why is that will I use ListView inside scrollView?

Comment: it doesn't necessarily have to be a scrollview, it can be a linerlayout view or relative view. I believe this problem that you're having is just being caused by the formatting of you layouts in your xml.

Comment: Actually whats happening here might shock you. Whenever listview show items say 5 items when home@botom is not visible.And then try to visible the home btn-listview will not change its height for sure.Try it for fun.You will know why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put one layout(Linearlayout) at bottom with "Wrap_content" and along_parentbottom=true  and inside that layout put your home bottom.
Now when you set home button visibility to GONE layout your layout still there with 0 height and when you make it visible its inside layuout so list does not cover whole part.

Comment: Yes it is covering.. & that creates the same problem. Try your self.

Comment: you might have to set listview above bottom Linearlayout.

Comment: What makes it difference. As complete xml - layout which includes listview is above Home button.

Comment: Have you check with you inflate fragment with attachtoroot=true?

Comment: Can you plz update your answer with code/line what you are saying?

Comment: Please refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean