# Gradle build Running consume(3 to 5 minute) to much time in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

When we run the android app then gradle build Running taking to 3 to five 5 munutes every time.  build.gradle(module app) is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sk.followkids"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.2.jar')
compile files('libs/PPNS-1.10.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.2.jar')
compile project(':facebook')
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.10.2.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

}

Thanks

Comment: this may be help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: i try but not work                                                                Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

As you can see

```
public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

The boolean param here its used to add the view as a child of the rootview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer,but  What is attachToRoot ? if i write bool true then why app  crash.

Comment: It means the view is going to be added to the rootView just like if you call addView(). whats your logcat exception? maybe you are calling addView() too?