# Where is the ViewGroup container initialized?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I am trying to understand the following fragment code:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment { 
    public FragmentA(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  if(container!=null)
                      // WHY IS THIS CODE EXECUTED? I did not set container variable


          // why if I pass null insted of Container, I get the same result?
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    }
}
```

This ViewGroup container I never initialized or something. How does android know what is my container?, if I never initialized it.

The other thing that is not clear to me is when I call inflate and if instead the container I write null, the result is same.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,null,false);
```

I am working with ViewPager in my main activity.

I create the fragment is this way in the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentA();
```

These are my xml files:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

and for the fragment :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFCC00" >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="THIS IS FRAGMENT A" />

</FrameLayout>
```

EDIT:
I found this on the developer site:

> The container parameter passed to onCreateView() is the parent
>   ViewGroup (from the activity's layout) in which your fragment layout
>   will be inserted. The savedInstanceState parameter is a Bundle that
>   provides data about the previous instance of the fragment, if the
>   fragment is being resumed (restoring state is discussed more in the
>   section about Handling the Fragment Lifecycle).

But, is still not clear for me. I did not pass any ViewGroup to the Fragment in the Fragment call....

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/why-does-layoutinflater-ignore-the-layout-width-and-layout-height-layout-paramet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean

Comment: @aldok I edited the question a Little bit. I read your links, but I still do not understand, I dont find my answer

Answer (score 0):

The container is supplied externally to the fragment. It's either generated automatically when you use the `<fragment>` tag in xml, or it's passed as part of the `FragmentTransaction` when you initialize the fragment in code.

Comment: I edited the answer, so is more clear what is my situation