# Android (Java): how to use LayoutInflater.inflate() for Dialogs?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, null

I'm using the `LayoutInflater` within a `Dialog` and don't know what to set as a **2nd** parameter, which is `null` for now.

I found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809756/1792858) for `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle bundle)`, but that method isn't available for a `Dialog`.

**Faking** the `null` by something like `(ViewGroup) null` is **not an option** for me.

**MyDialog**

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view               = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null); 
        // ________________ How to replace that null? ___________________^

        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

**Error** reported by [Infer](https://fbinfer.com):

```
MyDialog.java:42: error: ERADICATE_PARAMETER_NOT_NULLABLE
  `LayoutInflater.inflate(...)` needs a non-null value in parameter 2 but argument `null` can be null. (Origin: null constant at line 42).
  41.           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
  42. >         View view               = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_unlock, null);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**Solution**

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);

        Button myBtn         = findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
        EditText myTextField = findViewById(R.id.my_et);

        View.OnClickListener onClickMyBtn = v -> {
            String value = myTextField.getText().toString();
            Log.d("MyDialog", String.format("My value: %s", value));
            dismiss();
        };
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(onClickMyBtn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
```

Instead of this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
setContentView(view);
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {


    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    Button myBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);

        myBtn = findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == myBtn) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then create your dialog like this

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(this);
myDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, but how can I get the `View view` then? I need it to control a `Button` within the `Dialog`.

Comment: @Mr.B. you can directly `findViewById` do inside `onCreate()` method like this `Button yes = findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);` than you can perform action as per your requirement

Comment: @NileshRathod the problem is that, both methods are correct. His problem may be in context, `getContext()` may return null. Just pass context from your activity in a constructor, and your code will work. And sometimes code wont work, because there are needed all 3 arguments in `inflate()` method, here's only two.

Comment: @NileshRathod I didn't know that, thanks. Unfortunately I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when clicking on the button, that I attached a `View.OnClickListener` to: `myBtn.setOnClickListener(onClickMyBtn)`. Any idea?

Comment: @Mr.B. try updated answer first do `setContentView()` then do `findViewById()`

Comment: @Mr.B.You cannot initialize button before you'll set your view. So your code will be work, when you move all code below `setContentView()`, this should be always after `super` method.