# How to get the inflated view from AlertDialog when using setView(int layoutResId)?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I use this code to create a custom AlertDialog:

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(R.layout.layout)
            .create()
```

The problem is I cannot get the inflated view. `dialog.findViewById(R.id.a_view_in_the_layout)` returns null.

Alternatively, I can use `.setView(View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout, null)` but this sometimes makes the dialog fill the screen and take more space than `setView(int layoutResId)`.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54437691/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you. Subclassing Dialog seems a workable alternative but we'll lose other cool features that AlertDialog provides.

Comment: `dialog.findViewById crashes the app` what error you are getting

Comment: Please always clarify when something "crashes the app" - without more information, no one can help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: @dominicoder I've edited the question. It returns null and I cannot find other methods to find views.

Comment: @DeweyReed I have put my answer please have to look at it's very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `create` sets up the Dialog, but its layout is not inflated until it needs to be shown. Try calling `show` first then, then finding the view you're looking for.

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(R.layout.layout)
            .create()

dialog.show() // Cause internal layout to inflate views
dialog.findViewById(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just inflate the layout yourself (its Java code but I think you know what to do):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout, null );
dialog.setView(view);
dialog.create().show();
```

Your inflated view is now `view` and you can use it to find other views in it like:

```
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.myEdittext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `alert dialog` use `simple Dialog` its Easy and very simple

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView((R.layout.layout);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

You don't have to need to inflate the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
View dialogView; //define this as a gobal field

dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setView(dialogView);

View yourView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.a_view_in_the_layout);
TextView yourTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.a_textView_in_the_layout);
Button yourButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.a_button_in_the_layout);
```