# CustomAdapter-getView()-recycling views-How does the inflate() method work in returning the view?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

while creating a custom Adapter, i override getView method.
here(code below for recyling views), i don't understand how `LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)` is working.i understand the need of first and second parameter but why are we using the thrid parameter?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
       if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
       }
}
```

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView? It looks like ListView.

Comment: Check this answer:
[Third parameter (attachToRoot)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567640/8194042)