# Intent is not working inside fragment to open Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I'm trying to use Intent inside PlaceholderFragment class of TabActivity's fragment to open next Activity.

Here is my code:

**PlaceHolderFragment** class

```
    public ImageButton Next;
     public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab,container,true);
        Next=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updatedetails();
            }
        });

        View root=null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                 root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
                    break;
        }
        return root;
    }
public void updatedetails(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Enquiry_followup.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: No error but can't open the activity.I'll check in Logcat aslso

Comment: Put the Log.e() after startActivity(intent); line and see the log line print or not?

Comment: Try to put onClick listener inside method onViewCreated...

Comment: @Aniket_1994 Can you post logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

public ImageButton Next;

public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);


    View root = null;
    switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
            break;
    }

    Next = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            updatedetails();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public void updatedetails() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Enquiry_followup.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Rearrange the code like this. And make sure both the xml file contains the ImageButton with the id - **btn_expand**

The issue with your code was that the `onClickListener` was before setting the `view`.

Comment: Thank you so much @MilanJoseph...It will help for me just by setting view.

Comment: After using your code my SWITCH CASE Is not working.I'm not able to see different fields in  tab2.Only i can see same fields as present in tab 1 . @Milan Joseph

Comment: In switch I have given 1 hardcoded, Please provide your login. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below. Last param of the inflater, make it false.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab,container,false);
```

You should never pass attachToRoot as true when you are not responsible for adding the child view to parent.

You can read more about this from this answer @[NOW OR NOT NOW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809756/9292949)

Comment: does it reaches to startActivity() method when the code is run?

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` is not the best way for getting context in a fragment.
And make the attachToRoot = false while creating the view
Try the following code

```
public class yourClass{
public ImageButton Next;

 Context context;
@Override public void onAttach(Context context) { 
super.onAttach(context);
 this.context=context; 
}
     public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab,container,false);
        Next=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updatedetails();
            }
        });

        View root=null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                 root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
                    break;
        }
        return root;
    }
public void updatedetails(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Enquiry_followup.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Try this and post the update.

> Edit 1:Try returning rootView instead of root in onCreateView().