# Android RecyclerView rows have same data but different size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a RecyclerView with some components inside it. Everything works normally, and I think I have written everything properly, but some items have different size although all the data inside this rows are similar, but different in size. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="40dp">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/label_text_grey"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cargo"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Alma"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/label_text_heavy_black"
    android:fontFamily="@font/main_helvetica_neue_medium"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/metric"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Ton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/label_text_heavy_black"
    android:fontFamily="@font/main_helvetica_neue_medium"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="10000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/label_text_heavy_black"
    android:fontFamily="@font/main_helvetica_neue_medium"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/remove"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:tint="@color/close_icon_red"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Fragment:

```
class AddItemsFragment(val truck: Truck) : BaseFragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddItemsBinding
private lateinit var items: MutableList<AddedItem>
private lateinit var adapter: AddedItemsAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentAddItemsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.documentNo.text = truck.documentNo
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    val date = Date()
    binding.date.text = formatter.format(date)
    items = listOf(
        AddedItem("Alma", Metric("Ton", 3)),
        AddedItem("Armud", Metric("Sentner", 11)),
        AddedItem("Heyva", Metric("Sentner", 1)),
        AddedItem("Nar", Metric("KG", 980)),
        AddedItem("Pomidor", Metric("Ton", 2)),
        AddedItem("Pomidor", Metric("Ton", 2)),
        AddedItem("Pomidor", Metric("Ton", 2)),
        AddedItem("Kartof", Metric("Ton", 1)),
        AddedItem("Kartof", Metric("Ton", 1)),
        AddedItem("Pomidor", Metric("Ton", 1)),
        AddedItem("Pomidor", Metric("Ton", 1)),
        AddedItem("Kartof", Metric("Ton", 1)),
        AddedItem("Kartof", Metric("Ton", 1))
    ) as MutableList<AddedItem>
    val sampleMetrics = listOf(
        Metric("KG", 1),
        Metric("SENTNER", 100),
        Metric("TON", 1000)
    )

    adapter = AddedItemsAdapter(requireContext(), items)
    binding.items.adapter = adapter


    binding.metricItems.setAdapter(
        ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            sampleMetrics.map {
                it.name
            })
    )
    binding.scanIcon.setOnClickListener {
        //TODO open the scanner
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return binding.root
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onAddedItemRemovedEvent(event: AddedItemRemovedEvent){
    items.removeAt(event.position)
    adapter.itemRemoved(items, event.position)
}
}
```

And here is my Adapter:

```
class AddedItemsAdapter(val context: Context, var items: MutableList<AddedItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AddedItemsViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AddedItemsViewHolder {
    return AddedItemsViewHolder(ListitemAddedItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AddedItemsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.cargo.text = item.cargo
    holder.metric.text = item.metric.name
    holder.quantity.text = item.metric.size.toString()

    holder.remove.setOnClickListener {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(AddedItemRemovedEvent(position))
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun itemRemoved(newItems: MutableList<AddedItem>, position: Int){
    items = newItems
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
}
```

**Preview on phone**

[image]

Comment: Please share an activity/fragment code where you are setup adapter and preparing data.

Comment: You should add your adapter code too

Comment: Return this to your viewholder ListitemAddedItemsBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(context),
                parent,
                false
            )

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah , great, man, solved! But I cannot understand what is the problem, why should we give parent and attachToParent extra? And you can add your comment as answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return this to your viewholder

```
 ListitemAddedItemsBinding.inflate( LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false )
```

For more info [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567578/what-does-the-layoutinflater-attachtoroot-parameter-mean)